# waitgroup with concurrent limit but test fail

Tags: go

I use sync.WaitGroup with goroutine before, but I want to control the goroutine concurrency,

so I write my waitgroup with concurrency limit like:

```
package wglimit

import (
    "sync"
)

// WaitGroupLimit ...
type WaitGroupLimit struct {
    ch chan int
    wg *sync.WaitGroup
}

// New ...
func New(size int) *WaitGroupLimit {
    if size <= 0 {
        size = 1 
    }
    return &WaitGroupLimit{
        ch: make(chan int, size),  // buffer chan to limit concurrency
        wg: &sync.WaitGroup{},
    }
}

// Add ...
func (wgl *WaitGroupLimit) Add(delta int) {
    for i := 0; i < delta; i++ {
        wgl.ch <- 1
        wgl.wg.Add(1)
    }
}

// Done ...
func (wgl *WaitGroupLimit) Done() {
    wgl.wg.Done()
    <-wgl.ch
}

// Wait ...
func (wgl *WaitGroupLimit) Wait() {
    close(wgl.ch)
    wgl.wg.Wait()
}
```

And then I use it to control the goroutine concurrency, for example:

```
jobs := ["1", "2", "3", "4"] // some jobs

// wg := sync.WaitGroup{} // have no concurrency limit
wg := wglimit.New(2) // limit 2 goroutine
for _, job := range jobs {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(job string) {
        // job worker
        defer wg.Done()
    }(job)
}
wg.Wait()
```

And it looks like worked when running.

But Test Failed:

```
package wglimit

import (
    "runtime"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestGoLimit(t *testing.T) {
    var limit int = 5
    wglimit := New(limit)
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        wglimit.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wglimit.Done()
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
            if runtime.NumGoroutine() > limit+2 {
                println(runtime.NumGoroutine())  // will print 9 , cocurrent limit fail ?
                t.Errorf("FAIL")
            }
        }()
    }
    wglimit.Wait()
}
```

When testing, the goroutine numbers is bigger than my limit, it seems like the cocurrent limit fail.

Anything wrong with my WaitGroupLimit code and why?

Comment: If you used `fmt.Print("spawned")` with a 1 second delay it would better demonstrate if you have a problem or not. Your current `runtime`-based check does not look reliable (it at least has a race condition).

Comment: what is the expected behavior of this mechanism? if you attempt to write to a channel that is full, then it will throw an error. Is that what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anything wrong with my WaitGroupLimit code [...]?

No.

The problem is `runtime.NumGoroutine()` doesn't do what you seem to think it does. It counts *all* goroutines, i.e. not only the ones you start but also the goroutines the runtime uses itself, e.g. for concurrent garbage collection. NumGoroutine is thus higher than your limit.

Your code is fine, your test isn't. Do not try to get clever in testing and test what you code really does: It blocks on `Add` until the limited resource is available. Test that and not a goroutine count which is just a (bad) proxy for the desired behaviour in your test.